# HttpContext.Current.Session is null Privacy settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, internet-explorer-11

If we set on IE11 privacy settings to medium, we succesfully get our value from session, but if we set to "Block All Cookies" - we get null. What can cause it? How to avoid?

```
var x = HttpContext.Current.Session["user_name"]
```

Regards.

Comment: You can't avoid it, since no cookies are saved. So you can't retrieve the cookie either.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET uses a `session identifier` to identify users of your site.
By default, it places this value inside of your `.ASPNET_SessionId` cookie.

However, if it's disabled it obviously won't send the identifier to the server either.

A *possible* sollution would be [cookieless sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx), in which case your session identifier would be added to your url. Though this is of course ugly, and I'm not sure if there are any security concerns that go with it.

Do note that cookieless is not supported by ASP.NET MVC, but only through webforms.

Comment: But cann't use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code by adding in `Global.asax` file

```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");
   }
```

The problem lies with a W3C standard called *Platform for Privacy Preferences* or *P3P*.
This will allow Internet Explorer to accept your cookie. You will need to send the header on every page that sets a cookie.

Comment: Could you explain what this header does/means and how it solves the problem?

Comment: Didn't help. Any other ideas?